# How do I append at the end of row in in google sheets using python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am working on a project where i want to add values after the last row in google sheets, My code now i just overwriting the values if i rerun the code. For instance is i run the code twice i want to have double the values of whats inside the array "aoa" 7*2 rows.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1FL_OSVo82741728v_pMLlwiPx5fqS3WmoamM'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

#call the sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range="blad1").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

aoa = [['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220], ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220], ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220],
       ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220], ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220], ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220],
       ['value1', '1/111/2020', 5220]]


request = sheet.values.append().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range='blad1', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={'values':aoa}).execute()

print(values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
request = sheet.values.append().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range='blad1', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={'values':aoa}).execute()
```

**With:**

```
request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range='blad1', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={'values':aoa}).execute()
```

**Example:**

First Run:

[image]

Second Run:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: Since my reputation is below 15 i cannot upvote, only accept :P Just started this account